# Angular Material - Mat Table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material and I have been trying to set some styling to mat-table without any success. I need to change the border radius of the table itself and I also need to change the spacing inside the table to "space-between".I pretty much need this design: [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGBrw.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Go to page in chrome, press f12 and then inspect elements. Hover over the border and click. Look on the right under style. You see all the styles, experiment there to change radius and then override that style with your style in your component's Css file

Comment: @ובל צרפת - Try to change table background color to transparent - 

.mat-table
{
 background-color:transparent;  
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have add following css changes:-

```
.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;  // this change
}

.example-container{
  border-radius: 10px; // this change
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check whether you have applied border style for the mat-table. As per my knowledge mat-table does not add a border by default. If not please add border style and for making CSS applicable you need to use **/deep/** before the class name in css file.

```
/deep/ .mat-table {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 30%; 
        }
```

or you can add

```
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

in your component.ts as the argument in the **@component** decorator.